# phonegap + websocket : onOpen won't fire

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, websocket

I'm starting to work with phonegap + websocket + android . i've tried to execute this example but i couldn't make it.
http://anismiles.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/websocket-support-in-android%E2%80%99s-phonegap-apps/

all i receive in the server is this message  :

***GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: WebSocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: 192.168.1.21:10008
Origin: *
Sec-WebSocket-Key1: 1 4113 76776
Sec-WebSocket-Key2: 26 8P  2 2x 4#8  54c m'   !7
ó¥Þâtuv***

but i want to receive my own message (a simple hello world for the beginning).
Any one can help :)